Оптимизация сайта с помощью подгрузки div блоков с контентом из VK
Есть в ВК такая функция как поделиться, а там экспорт и копировать для сайта. Проблема в том что при слишком большом количестве постов сайт загружает их все нагружая неимоверно браузер, а время на подгрузку всех постов можно высчитывать в световых годах. Можно ли распределить эти посты по блокам и подгружать по отдельности, а не всем скопом. Сколько я бы не искал решения находил лишь отдельные примеры подгрузки картинок, текста, блоков(не работает с постами).
